# Extended Object.prototype function called upon page load

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a function to the Object prototype. For now, I'm simply doing this:

```
Object.prototype.consoleThis = function () {
    console.log(this);
};
```

Then embedding the code into the `head`. Then I try to use the new function:

```
var basicObject = {"name": "basicObject"};
basicObject.consoleThis();
```

However, in the console, a paragraph element from my HTML has been logged into the console, like so:

```
<p id="comment" class="ng-binding">
    This is a comment
</p>
```

Which is followed by the expected logging of the `basicObject` object. Why is this? How can I stop this from happening?

**Edit: Found the source**

In my JavaScript, the new function is called like so, including surrounding JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#codeComments").css({height: $(".codeViewPre").height()});
    var basicObject = {
        "f": "abvc"
    };
    basicObject.consoleThis();
});
```

Removing the `$("#codeComments").css({height: $(".codeViewPre").height()});` line removes the logged paragraph from the console. Unfortunately, I don't see why this is happening.

Comment: That's one of the risks of assigning to `Object.prototype`. You can impact third-party code which doesn't expect `Object.prototype` to be extended. You might solve this by using `Object.defineProperty` and make the property non-enumerable.

Comment: Please check if that paragraph is logged by this function only. There is a high chance that you have logged it by some other `console.log` and missing it now.

Comment: I am currently using the following 3rd part libraries, if anybody knows of any potential errors with extending the prototype with these libraries; Angular.js, Prisim.js and jQuery.

Comment: Removing this function removes the logging of the paragraph.

Comment: Is the paragraph logged if you add the method to `Object.prototype`, but do not call `basicObject.consoleThis();`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, the paragraph is logged regardless if the function is never actually called

Comment: If you use [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.trace), you will know where it comes from.

Comment: Unless a 3rd party library makes a statement that extending `Object.prototype` is safe to do with their library, I would work with the assumption that it's unsafe. It's definitely unsafe with jQuery.

Comment: I have found the source of the issue, My question isn't a dupe though. There is this line before it in my JavaScript: $("#codeComments").css({height: $(".codeViewPre").height()}); Removing this removes the mystery logging.